# Wordpress Contact Form - sending form to group email

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form-7, contact-form

I'm having a small issue with my contact form on the WordPress site.
I'm currently using Contact Form 7 and I would like the Contact Form to be sent to the email group that's being set up within Office 365 for the company.

For example, I have 5 emails:

```
john@company.com
matt@company.com
lucy@company.com
george@company.com
jo@company.com
```

they are included inside `main-group@company.com`. So anything that's sent to `main-group@company.com` - it'll be delivered to those 5 people.

I would like the WordPress Contact Form to use `main-group@company.com` instead of putting manually all email addresses.

Do you know if it's possible to do with Contact Form 7? Or maybe do I need to use a different plugin? Or maybe Office 365 is not set up correctly?

I will appreciate any advice, suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In CF7 settings, change the `TO` address to `main-group@company.com`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the CF7 very well and I've worked a lot with this plugin.

I've already tried adding ```main-group@company.com``` inside ```TO``` section but there are no emails coming through.

Or do you think there could a firewall blocking the emails?

Comment: Try to install a plugin that uses smtp to send mail. https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-smtp/